# Windows domain login via proxy website

Tags: proxy, domain, website

I have a software that hosts a website that is protected via domain auth. When accessing this website within the domain, I will see the dashboard of the software.

Now my problem is, that I want to display this information on a smart tv that via the internet browser. I can't add the tv to the domain so when accessing the website the authorization fails.

I thought that maybe I can run some kind of proxy website that runs within the domain and just proxys the website to the own website so when accessing the proxy website at the tv I will see my software website because the authentification already happens via the proxy webserver domain.

Is something like that possible?

Comment: Why don't you connect the TV to a computer as monitor?

Comment: Thats not an option I have. i need a solution that uses the web browser

Comment: Only way I can think of for allowing external connections to the domain is to establish a VPN server inside the domain, if the TV is smart enough for it.